# Getting value of a Text Field from a VBox

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently adding a `TextField` and a corresponding `ComboBox` dynamically every time a button is pressed. Is there a way outside of my method to then use the `VBox` (fieldContainer) variable to get the `TextField` and `ComboBox` values?

**EDIT**

I am creating an application in which the user can connect to a database and create a table. The scene in which the user creates the table has a `TextField` for the table name and a `TextField` for the column name with a corresponding `ComboBox` to select the column type.

[image: create table scene]

when the user clicks on add field, it generates another `TextField` and `ComboBox` bellow the current one, so now the table as two columns, etc...

I then later want to grab the values (with the code bellow) when the user clicks create so I can organize it as a proper SQL statement.

**Code**

```
addTableField.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {             
        HBox box = new HBox(10);

        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>(fieldTypes);
        combo.setPromptText("type");

        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setPromptText("field label");

        box.getChildren().addAll(field, combo);

        fieldContainer.getChildren().addAll(box);
        window.sizeToScene();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? When do you want to get the values from these controls? You probably just need to add some object whose properties are bound to the values into a data structure of some kind, but without any context the question is basically unanswerable. Please create a [MCVE] that shows what you want to do here.

Comment: @James_D I expanded on the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Why not use a `TableView` for this?

Comment: @James_D I am new to javaFX I will look into TableView. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a class to hold the data which (if I understand correctly) will form each row of the resulting table. Create an object from this class when you create the `HBox`, bind the data in the object to the data in the controls, and add the object to a list. Then later you can just examine the contents of the list.

Something like:

```
public class Row {
    private final StringProperty label = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
    public StringProperty labelProperty() {
        return label ;
    }
    public final String getLabel() {
        return labelProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setLabel(String label) {
        labelProperty().set(label);
    }

    public final StringProperty type = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public StringProperty typeProperty() {
        return type ;
    }
    public final String getType() {
        return typeProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setType(String type) {
       typeProperty().set(type);
    }
}
```

Now in your main code you do:

```
final List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();

addTableField.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {             
        HBox box = new HBox(10);

        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>(fieldTypes);
        combo.setPromptText("type");

        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setPromptText("field label");

        box.getChildren().addAll(field, combo);

        fieldContainer.getChildren().addAll(box);

        Row row = new Row();
        rows.add(row);
        row.labelProperty().bind(field.textProperty());
        row.typeProperty().bind(combo.valueProperty()); // might need to worry about null values...

        window.sizeToScene();
    }
});
```

Then when the user clicks "Create" you can just iterate through `rows`, which will have one object for each `HBox` you created, with `getLabel()` and `getType()` giving the values in the corresponding controls in the respective `HBox`.

Comment: worked wonderfully, thank you. the only thing I needed to change was I believe you had a typo on the getLabel() method, it needed to return label.get();

Comment: `labelProperty().get()` is what I intended, though `label.get()` works too. Updated accordingly. (`labelProperty().get()` allows overriding `labelProperty()`, which I didn't make `final`, without violating the principal that `labelProperty().get()` should always return the same value as `getLabel()`...)